# Distribution of number of special elements chosen: m choices of n items with k special items

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

Suppose I a set with $n$ items, $k$ of which have a certain property($k\leq n$), and I choose $m$ items randomly from that set($m\leq n$), what is the distribution of the number of chosen items having that property? An item can only be chosen once.

I expect an answer in the form $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 f(k,n,m) \\
 g(k,n,m)
\end{array}
\right)$, but I don't know $f(k,n,m)$ and $g(k,n,m)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by counting all samples of $m$ elements from the population of $n$; this can be done $n \choose m$ ways.   Suppose exactly $l$ of the $k$ special items are chosen; let us enumerate the possibilities. There are $k\choose l$ ways to choose the special items and then $n-k\choose m -l$ ways to choose the non-special ones.  Now divide; here we assume all samples are equiprobable.  We get

$$P(\hbox{exactly $l$ special elements}) = {{k \choose l}{n - k\choose m -l}\over{n\choose m}}\qquad 1\le k \le m$$ This is called a hypergeometric distribution.